# How to enable or disable incognito keyboard programmatically in android?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, incognito-mode

My system is using google keyboard automatically. Is it possible to enable or disable incognito mode from google keyboard? My OS version is 9.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to put one **flag** on your edittext
**setImeOptions** from where you opening keyboard as below

```
 EditText editText;
 editText.setImeOptions(IME_FLAG_NO_PERSONALIZED_LEARNING);
```

add this line when you want to enable incognito keyboard.